# Substract 2 time fields in a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to build a small logBook for pilots, where a user inputs the take off time and the time he landed and the forms returns below that duration in the form: 02:34 hrs i.e 2 hours 34 minutes. 
on the models.py side this is how I set it up:

```
take_off_time = models.TimeField()
land_time = models.TimeField()
tot_time_field = models.DurationField()
```

model.Duration doesn't seem to be the answer here...
On the forms.py so far I simply rendered the model.

So the questions are:

1. What could i use instead of durationField?
2. How can I take the inputs and render the calculation?

I have tried in the models.py a simple:

```
def get_total_time(self):
    self.tot_time_field = self.land_time - self.take_off_time
    return self.tot_time
```

and then use tot_time in the form but I am not sure this is correct.

Comment: what is your difficulty using the duration field? it takes a python timedelta which you can abstract from your take of and land fields right?

Comment: Hi Hedde, thanks for answering, so in other words my example is correct? Should  I implement the time delta, and if yes how?

Comment: substracting datetime objects will result in timedelta objects, so you could overwrite your model's save method and call get_total_time before actually saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hedde van der Heide put me in the right direction, and i finally found an answer.
First i set a total_time like so:

```
def time_delta(self):
    t = self.land_time - self.take_off_time
    return str(td)
```

then i saved it :

```
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.tot_time_field = self.time_delta()
        super(Log,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

i changed `tot_time_field = models.DurationField()` in the models to:

```
tot_time_field = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)because i couldn't make the duration field work.
```

Last but not least, the models first two models had to be changed to DateTimeField
instead of TimeField because the time_delta(td) wouldn't work otherwise so to wrap it up:
models.py:

```
take_off_time = models.TimeField()
land_time = models.TimeField()
total_time_field = models.Charfield()

def time_delta(self):
    t = self.land_time - self.take_off_time
    return str(td)

def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.tot_time_field = self.time_delta()
    super(Log,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Hope that helps....

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    def save(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs):
        if not self.tot_time_field:
            self.tot_time_field = self.get_total_time()
        super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```